# Inserting HTML form data comes up blank

Tags: php, html

I am trying to send info I enter into an HTML form, into a MySQL database table. The function works, BUT...It enters BLANK data into the Mysql Database

I dont know what else to try. I am really new to this

THIS IS MY HTML FORM:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Date">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">The date the team went to the job site</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="job_number">Job Number</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="job_number" placeholder="JC2020">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="job_name">Job Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="job_name" placeholder="AVI Tender">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="team_name">Team Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="team_name" placeholder="Shane">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pastel_code">Pastel Code</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pastel_code" placeholder="012">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="vrn">Vehicle Registration</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vrn" placeholder="ND 123-456">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

THIS IS MY PHP file that processes the data:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$date= $_POST['date'];
$job_number= $_POST['job_number'];
$team_name= $_POST['team_name'];
$pastel_code= $_POST['pastel_code'];
$vrn= $_POST['vrn'];
$job_name= $_POST['job_name'];


$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO job_records (date, job_number, team_name, pastel_code, vrn, job_name)
VALUES ('$date', '$job_number', '$team_name', '$pastel_code', '$vrn', '$job_name')";

$conn->exec($sql);
echo "<script>alert('Data successfully added!'); window.location='dataentry.php'</script>";
?>
```

After submitting the form, a message displays saying the data was added, then redirects to the "master data" page with ALL the entries i have entered over time. But all entries i process come out BLANK. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: give the form elements a `name` attribute - the `id` attribute will NOT appear in the POST array

Comment: You have tried to create sql injection despite using PDO to protect yourself from that. You DO NOT put the data directly in the query, you have to put placeholders and BIND your data to the query.

Comment: Plus you write and test code, apparently without having proper PHP error reporting enabled. Go do that first of all now! (And research it please, if that keyword doesn’t mean anything to you yet.)

Comment: Yes i know, i will be fixing the SQL injection problems now since i got the form to actually add the info to the database. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned each form element requires a `name` attribute in order that it will appear in the POST array when the form is submitted. An ID attribute is mainly of use when interacting with the DOM using Javascript so really are not required below / above.

```
<form action='' method='post'>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='date'>Date</label>
    <input type='date' class='form-control' id='date' name='date' aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='Date'>
    <small id='emailHelp' class='form-text text-muted'>The date the team went to the job site</small>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='job_number'>Job Number</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='job_number' name='job_number' placeholder='JC2020'>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='job_name'>Job Name</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='job_name' name='job_name' placeholder='AVI Tender'>
  </div>

 <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='team_name'>Team Name</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='team_name' name='team_name' placeholder='Shane'>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='pastel_code'>Pastel Code</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='pastel_code' name='pastel_code' placeholder='012'>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='vrn'>Vehicle Registration</label>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='vrn' name='vrn' placeholder='ND 123-456'>
  </div>

  <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

That said the main issue, which has been addressed in comments, is that of `SQL injection` vulnerabilities - one of the benefits of both `PDO` and `mySQLi` are `prepared statements`. As you are using PDO perhaps this might be of use:

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        require_once('config.php');

        $args=array(
            'date'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'job_number'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'team_name'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'pastel_code'   =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
            'vrn'           =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
            'job_name'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
        );
        $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );


        $params=array();

        $sql='insert into `job_records` ( `date`, `job_number`, `team_name`, `pastel_code`, `vrn`, `job_name` ) values ( :date, :job_number, :team_name, :pastel_code, :vrn, :job_name )';
        foreach( array_keys( $args ) as $key ){
            $params[ ':'.$key ] = ${$key};
        }

        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
        $res = $stmt->execute( $params );

        exit( header( sprintf( 'Location: dataentry.php?status=%s', $res ? 'ok' : 'fail' ) ) );
    }
?>
```

---

demo - tested and appears to function OK

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        try{

            /* PDO connection */
            $dbport =   3306;
            $dbhost =   'localhost';
            $dbuser =   'root'; 
            $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
            $dbname =   'xxx';

            $options=array( 
                PDO::ATTR_CURSOR                    =>  PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL,
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT                =>  false,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY  =>  true,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES          =>  true,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND        =>  'SET NAMES \'utf8mb4\' COLLATE \'utf8mb4_unicode_ci\', @@sql_mode = STRICT_ALL_TABLES, @@foreign_key_checks = 1'
            );

            $dsn='mysql:host='.$dbhost.';port='.$dbport.';dbname='.$dbname.';charset=UTF8';
            $db = $conn = new PDO( $dsn, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $options );



            /* disabled as not relevant in demo */
            #require_once('config.php');


            $args=array(
                'date'          =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'job_number'    =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'team_name'     =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'pastel_code'   =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
                'vrn'           =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
                'job_name'      =>  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
            );
            $_POST=filter_input_array( INPUT_POST, $args );
            extract( $_POST );


            $errors=array();
            $params=array();
            $keys=array_keys( $args );


            /* dynamically build sql query from $args array */
            $sql=sprintf('insert into `job_records` 
                            ( `%s` ) 
                            values 
                            ( :%s ) ', 
                            implode( '`,`', $keys ),
                            implode( ', :', $keys )
                        );

            /* check that each variable is set else throw exception and continue */
            foreach( array_keys( $args ) as $key ){
                try{
                    /* test variable variable against those generated by `extract` above */
                    if( empty( ${$key} ) ) throw new Exception( sprintf( 'empty field: %s', $key ) );

                    /* add the parameter to the args to be executed */
                    $params[ ':'.$key ] = ${$key};
                }catch( Exception $e ){
                    $errors[]=$e->getMessage();
                    continue;
                }
            }

            /* If all went well execute the query & redirect user */
            if( !empty( $params ) && empty( $errors ) && !empty( $conn ) ){

                $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
                if( !$stmt ) throw new PDOException('Failed to prepare SQL Query');
                $res = $stmt->execute( $params );

                exit( header( sprintf( 'Location: dataentry.php?status=%s', $res ? 'ok' : 'fail' ) ) ); 
            }

            if( !empty( $errors ) ) printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($errors,true) );


        }catch( PDOException $e ){
            exit( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>PDO form test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='' method='post'>

          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='date'>Date</label>
            <input type='date' class='form-control' id='date' name='date' aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='Date'>
            <small id='emailHelp' class='form-text text-muted'>The date the team went to the job site</small>
          </div>

          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='job_number'>Job Number</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' id='job_number' name='job_number' placeholder='JC2020'>
          </div>

          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='job_name'>Job Name</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' id='job_name' name='job_name' placeholder='AVI Tender'>
          </div>

         <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='team_name'>Team Name</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' id='team_name' name='team_name' placeholder='Shane'>
          </div>

          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='pastel_code'>Pastel Code</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' id='pastel_code' name='pastel_code' placeholder='012'>
          </div>

          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='vrn'>Vehicle Registration</label>
            <input type='text' class='form-control' id='vrn' name='vrn' placeholder='ND 123-456'>
          </div>

          <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh, I think I see why perhaps.... `$stmt=conn->prepare( $sql );` should be `$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );`

Comment: Yeah i picked that up and changed it before you replied (which i am quite proud of hehehe), but now i get "masterdata.php?status=fail" in my URL and no data is entered into database :( Doing some research on that now

Comment: I just rattled this up as a demo and it worked OK. I'll add the modified code below what I posted earlier

Comment: Works like a charm man, Thanks so much. Now i am going to research what you did so i can get a better understanding of it all. **Still a Newbie** Thanks so much, really appreciate your help. This was actually for cancelling out a manual process here at work and having a digital process in place. My boss will be pleased! :)

Answer (score -1):

Your code is correct but the error create on your input field 
In simple and short use name(Attribute) on the input field and pass that name to save the data.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="lastName">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="emailAddress">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Retrive form value and insert in to database

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['first_name']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['last_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['email']);

// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Conclusion for your code error

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO job_records ('database column name with comma seperated')
VALUES ('Input variable value seperated by comma')";
```